# How Can This Java For Loop Be More Readable?

Tags: java, loops

I am trying to figure out a way to achieve this without so much repetition, I have tried using more for loops, but since each array has to been looped through so differently I am struggling.

```java
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  warray[i][0] = narray[i][0] * pcarray[i][0];
  warray[i][1] = narray[i][0] * pcarray[i][1];
  warray[i][2] = narray[i][1] * pcarray[i][0];
  warray[i][3] = narray[i][1] * pcarray[i][1];
  warray[i][4] = narray[i][2] * pcarray[i][0];
  warray[i][5] = narray[i][2] * pcarray[i][1];
  warray[i][6] = narray[i][3] * pcarray[i][0];
  warray[i][7] = narray[i][3] * pcarray[i][1];
  warray[i][8] = narray[i][4] * pcarray[i][0];
  warray[i][9] = narray[i][4] * pcarray[i][1];
  warray[i][10] = narray[i][5] * pcarray[i][0];
  warray[i][11] = narray[i][5] * pcarray[i][1];
  warray[i][12] = narray[i][6] * pcarray[i][0];
  warray[i][13] = narray[i][6] * pcarray[i][1];
  warray[i][14] = narray[i][7] * pcarray[i][0];
  warray[i][15] = narray[i][7] * pcarray[i][1];
  warray[i][16] = narray[i][8] * pcarray[i][0];
  warray[i][17] = narray[i][8] * pcarray[i][1];
  warray[i][18] = narray[i][9] * pcarray[i][0];
  warray[i][19] = narray[i][9] * pcarray[i][1];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

While different, they do follow a pattern:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++ ) 
        warray [i][j] = narray [i][j/2] * pcarray[i][j%2];
```

Comment: beat me to it by a couple seconds!

Comment: you might need to cast to int or floor `j/2`

Comment: @JannesCarpentier no. `j/2` is an `int`.